# How to do complex filters on three or more DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

**I want to populate columns using filters based on several DataFrames values as conditions**.

**Using the code bellow creates three DataFrames:**

```
print(main_df.tail())

            Date       Code start_date   end_date   nums    furniture
18934 2021-02-17  84QQP49YJ 2018-07-25 2021-02-17  three        chest
18935 2021-02-17  89IA4XDIU 2018-11-27 2021-02-17   five          bed
18936 2021-02-17  8LIFYW7LB 2020-05-16 2021-02-17    six         sofa
18937 2021-02-17  8ZF080G5U 2020-04-08 2021-02-17  three  coffe_table
18938 2021-02-17  9B9R0JIBB 2020-08-25 2021-02-17  three         sofa

print(second_df.tail())

             Date       Code  values     colors
107509 2023-11-07  1E5M1DVZI   86799      green
107510 2023-11-07  3P3VTOSN0   96229    magenta
107511 2023-11-07  910TL0TMF   93852  dark_blue
107512 2023-11-07  21JZU3AB5   92032      white
107513 2023-11-07  7CBK4U5F2   52470     yellow

print(third_df.tail())

            Date    Shapes  quantity
21896 2023-11-07      star     85367
21897 2023-11-07    circle     23269
21898 2023-11-07      oval     37599
21899 2023-11-07  squiggle     52118
21900 2023-11-07   octagon     42500
```

I'll explain the logic to understand how to filter based on these types of conditions.

**Case 1:** Add new column named *"new_value"* on main_df

(main_df.new_value = second_df.value) when

(main_df.date == second_df.date) and

(main_df.code == second_df.code)

**Case 2:** Add new column named *"color"* on main_df

(main_df.color = second_df.colors) when

(main_df.code == second_df.code) and

(main_df.start_date <= second_df.date <= main_df.end_date)

Should there be more than one match, pick the first.

**Case 3:** On main_df add new column *"mixed_quantity"*

main_df.mixed_quantity = (third_df.quantity + second_df.values) if

('main_df.date == second_df.date == third_df.date) and

(main_df.Code == second_df.Code), and

(third_df.Shape == 'circle'). This field will have Nans, that's ok.

**Case 4:** Add a new column on main_df *"furniture_value"*

main_df.furniture_value = second_df.values/10 if

(main_df.furniture == 'chest') and (main_df.date == second_df.date)

main_df.furniture_value = second_df.values/15 if

(main_df.furniture == 'bed') and (main_df.date == second_df.date)

main_df.furniture_value = second_df.values/20 if

(main_df.furniture == 'sofa') and (main_df.date == second_df.date)

and so on..

similar to a switch statement. For this I was able to use iterrows but it took over 30 minutes to run on the original dataset. Which is unfeasible.

I have tried all manners of and so much more. I'll avoid writing the overtly complex loops I've done.:

```py
 main_df.new_value = main_df[(main_df.date == second_df.date) & (main_df.code == second_df.code)]

 second_df.date.reset_index(drop=True) == main_df.date.reset_index(drop=True)) & (third_df.Shape == 'circle')]
```

and similar and I have gotten index errors. And so many other errors.

```
    raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I just don't know how to handle these complex conditions.

**The code to generate the dataset:**

In order to make my questions more clear I made some **code to generate a dataset** that has the proper conditions: structure and the size.

Note: I use the library [pyjanitor](https://pypi.org/project/pyjanitor/) to make a conditional join faster.

```py
import random
import string
from datetime import datetime
import janitor
import pandas as pd

initial_date = pd.to_datetime('5/27/2018')
today = pd.to_datetime(datetime.today()).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
date_range = pd.date_range(start=initial_date, end=today)
date_range = pd.Series(date_range, name='Date')

shapes = ['square', 'triangle', 'rhomboid', 'trapezoid', 'pentagon', 'hexagon', 'star', 'circle',
              'oval', 'squiggle', 'octagon']


def alph_num_generator(n, a=False):
    def single_alphanumeric():
        random_string = ''.join(
            # random.choice(string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(8))
            random.choice(string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(8))
        return str(random.randint(1, 9)) + random_string

    if a:
        random_alphanumeric_list = [single_alphanumeric() for x in range(n)]
        return random_alphanumeric_list
    else:
        random_numeric_list = [random.randint(10_000, 99_999) for x in range(n)]
        return random_numeric_list


def date_pair_list(start_r, end_r, n):
    def pair_generator(begin, end):
        date_list = pd.date_range(begin, end).date
        first_half = random.randint(0, round(len(date_list) / 2 - 1))
        second_half = random.randint(round(len(date_list) / 2 - 1),
                                     len(date_list) - round(len(date_list) / 2 - 1))
        left_day, right_day = date_list[first_half], date_list[second_half]
        return [left_day, right_day]

    both = [pair_generator(start_r, end_r) for x in range(n)]
    left, right = [x[0] for x in both], [x[1] for x in both]
    return left, right


def random_list_generator(i, n):
    colors = ['red', 'green', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'light_blue', 'dark_blue', 'black', 'white',
              'pink', 'orange', 'crimson', 'teal']
    shapes = ['square', 'triangle', 'rhomboid', 'trapezoid', 'pentagon', 'hexagon', 'star', 'circle',
              'oval', 'squiggle', 'octagon']
    fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'lemon', 'pineapple', 'watermelon', 'lime',
              'tangerine', 'grapefruit', 'grapes']
    furniture = ['table', 'chair', 'armoire', 'chest', 'bed', 'night_stand', 'coffe_table',
                 'sofa', 'bench', 'bookcase', 'stool']
    nums = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven']
    map_to_type = {1: colors, 2: shapes, 3: fruits, 4: furniture, 5: nums}

    def random_value_generator(j):
        rand_num = random.randint(0, 10)
        return map_to_type[j][rand_num]

    output = [random_value_generator(i) for x in range(n)]
    return output


Code = alph_num_generator(37, a=True)
start_date, end_date = date_pair_list(initial_date, today, 37)
start_date, end_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date), pd.to_datetime(end_date)
nums = random_list_generator(5, 37)
src_df = pd.DataFrame({'Code': Code, 'start_date': start_date, 'end_date': end_date, 'nums': nums})
main_df = src_df.conditional_join(date_range, ('start_date', 'Date', '<='),
                                  ('end_date', 'Date', '>='), use_numba=False)
main_df = main_df[['Date', 'Code', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'nums']] \
    .sort_values(['Date', 'Code']).reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)
furniture = random_list_generator(4, int(main_df.shape[0]))
main_df = main_df.assign(furniture=furniture)

extra_code = Code + alph_num_generator(17, a=True)
secondary_code, secondary_date = pd.DataFrame({'Code': extra_code}), pd.DataFrame({'Date': date_range})
second_df = pd.merge(secondary_date, secondary_code, how='cross')
values, colors = alph_num_generator(second_df.shape[0]), random_list_generator(1, second_df.shape[0])
second_df = second_df.assign(values=values, colors=colors)

third_shapes, third_date = pd.DataFrame({'Shapes': shapes}), pd.DataFrame({'Date': date_range})
third_df = pd.merge(third_date, third_shapes, how='cross')
third_quanitity = alph_num_generator(int(third_df.shape[0]))
third_df = third_df.assign(quantity=third_quanitity)
del secondary_code, secondary_date, extra_code, values, colors, nums, third_date, third_quanitity, third_shapes, src_df
```